# Baked normal turned out weird

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, normals, texture-baking

I am new to blender and was following a tutorial where I wanted to bake a normal map from a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh.

On finishing baking the normal map turned out weird. I tried various extrusion and ray distance values(I dont know what extrusion does). But it still turned out wrong.

I have a feeling that I did something wrong while sculpting.
[image]

[image]

Here is the blend file I am working with.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14xmpw7HWBSs5hGiOXNs609RYpnqFPbZg?usp=sharing
Reference:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The normal map seems correct (no green or yellow splotches). Could you please elaborate on what you think the issue is or what result you expected?

Comment: The detailing I did with the high poly mesh didn't come through. The smaller details and all. It would be visible if the high poly mesh is rendered separately. It's more like a flat texture.

Comment: IIRC that tutorial feeds the normal map into a bump map.  In that case the problem could just be your lighting, since bump maps fake detail and need lighting across the surfaces to create the shadows.

Comment: @MartyFouts I did try both and both turned out wrong, the tutorial uses normal map so I used the same.

Comment: normal map is right.  I was wrong.  Anyway, in your blend file I can clearly see the problem and it's definitely not a lighting issue.  The areas where the detail is missing match areas of 'green' on the baked normals, FWIW.

Comment: @MartyFouts So what do you suggest I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure.   Did you edit the low poly anvil after you created it from the high poly?  When I look at the UV Map it doesn't seem to quiet match where the edges are on the Normal map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the answer when I redid the entire project. Basically I had slightly modified the high poly mesh which had messed up the baked normal texture. But when I redid the entire thing it turned out okay.